# how to make only one item to be checkable in the menu item's list on enabling ischeckable=true of all items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my code i have tried implementing that only one item can be checked at a particular time from menu items,but my code is giving `error-MenuKinect` (name of my solution) is an undeclared prefix,please explain how to resolve this error?

```
xaml code-
     <Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" Width="171" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF004165">
<MenuItem Header="Settings">
                    <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="headerLogoutTime" Header="LogOut Time" Background="#FF004165">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="header10Min" Header="10 Min"  Background="#FF004165" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup"  Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}"  ></MenuItem>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                        <MenuItem x:Name="header20Min" Header="20 Min"  Background="#FF004165" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup" Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" ></MenuItem>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                        <MenuItem x:Name="header30Min" Header="30 Min"  Background="#FF004165" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup" Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}"   ></MenuItem>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                        <MenuItem x:Name="header40Min" Header="40 Min"  Background="#FF004165" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup" Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}" ></MenuItem>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                        <MenuItem x:Name="header50Min" Header="50 Min"  Background="#FF004165" IsCheckable="True" MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup" Style="{StaticResource MyMenuItem}"  ></MenuItem>
                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                    <MenuItem Header="LogOut" Background="#FF004165" ></MenuItem>
                    <Separator Style="{StaticResource SeparatorStyleKey}" />

                </MenuItem>

            </Menu>
```

MenuItemExtensions.cs

```
public class MenuItemExtensions : DependencyObject
    {
    public static Dictionary<MenuItem, String> ElementToGroupNames = new Dictionary<MenuItem, String>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GroupName",
                                     typeof(String),
                                     typeof(MenuItemExtensions),
                                     new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnGroupNameChanged));

    public static void SetGroupName(MenuItem element, String value)
    {
        element.SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static String GetGroupName(MenuItem element)
    {
        return element.GetValue(GroupNameProperty).ToString();
    }

    private static void OnGroupNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add an entry to the group name collection
        var menuItem = d as MenuItem;

        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            String newGroupName = e.NewValue.ToString();
            String oldGroupName = e.OldValue.ToString();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroupName))
            {
                //Removing the toggle button from grouping
                RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                //Switching to a new group
                if (newGroupName != oldGroupName)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldGroupName))
                    {
                        //Remove the old group mapping
                        RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(menuItem);
                    }
                    ElementToGroupNames.Add(menuItem, e.NewValue.ToString());
                    menuItem.Checked += MenuItemChecked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveCheckboxFromGrouping(MenuItem checkBox)
    {
        ElementToGroupNames.Remove(checkBox);
        checkBox.Checked -= MenuItemChecked;
    }


    static void MenuItemChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
        foreach (var item in ElementToGroupNames)
        {
            if (item.Key != menuItem && item.Value == GetGroupName(menuItem))
            {
                item.Key.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declare namespace at root level to use class object in XAML.**

You can define it at root level (window or UserControl) or may be at root menu as well.

```
<Menu xmlns:MenuKinect="clr-namespace:Namespace_Name>"
```

Replace `Namespace_Name` with actual namespace where `MenuItemExtensions` class is defined.

Comment: <Window x:Class="MenuKinect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MenuKinect"
       <Menu xmlns:MenuKinect="clr-namespace:MenuKinect>"

Comment: I have included like this,it is giving error namespace not correct

Comment: `MenuKinect` namespace and where this XAML resides are in same assembly (project)?

Comment: Also if you have already define `local` namespace, no need to re-declare it with other name. You can use it like this `local:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup"`.

Comment: but when i have not declared local namespace,then at that time i was writing MenuKinect:MenuItemExtensions.GroupName="LogOutTimeGroup" why it was not working?

Comment: You have declared `MenuKinect` at that time at root level?